# Data cleaning, validation & Test driven development

Tags: unit-testing, validation, testing

I am working with an application which connects to an external vendor. Data arrives asynchronously, and a number of the application's 'components' use the data. The data has passed syntactical validation prior to entering the system, however each 'component' has varying definitions on whether the data is usable or not based on their own rules.

When considering test-driven development for each of these components, what is the 'best practice' for design regarding cleansing + validation of data?  Assuming here that the COMPONENT1_VALIADTION and COMPONENT_1 would have separate test cases. If data first goes through the COMPONENT1_VALIADTION as above, is it acceptable for the test cases and implementation of component_1,2,3 to assume cleaned data? Possibly then a systems test could ensure data is cleaned before the component_x is ever called?

```
EXTERNAL_DATA_SOURCE -> [ASYNC_CALLBACK -> COMPONENT1_VALIADTION -> COMPONENT_1]
EXTERNAL_DATA_SOURCE -> [ASYNC_CALLBACK -> COMPONENT2_VALIADTION -> COMPONENT_2]
EXTERNAL_DATA_SOURCE -> [ASYNC_CALLBACK -> COMPONENT3_VALIADTION -> COMPONENT_3]
```

Theoretically it could also look like:

```
EXTERNAL_DATA_SOURCE -> [ASYNC_CALLBACK -> [ COMPONENT1_VALIADTION -> COMPONENT_1] ]
EXTERNAL_DATA_SOURCE -> [ASYNC_CALLBACK -> [ COMPONENT2_VALIADTION -> COMPONENT_2] ]
EXTERNAL_DATA_SOURCE -> [ASYNC_CALLBACK -> [ COMPONENT3_VALIADTION -> COMPONENT_3] ]
```

Where the component tested is  [ COMPONENT1_VALIADTION -> COMPONENT_X]. Such that each component contains the validation itself. However this complicates things if i want multiple components using the same validation rule, or want to actually test the validation component separately?

I am trying to avoid every tier of the application requiring data validation..

Thanks in advance,

curious1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly this appears to be more of a design question then a unit testing question. Depending on how complex the data validation is, it may be a very good idea to separate out the data validation components from the actual component of the application. That way a developer looking at the component does not have to wade through all of the validation code. Also, if you can reuse the same validation component across several different components this would probably be a good design decision.

What you need to do is develop a "contract" for each of your components. This is most likely just in the form of class and method documentation explaining what this component is expecting for input and what it will return as output. You then would write unit tests making sure your code adheres to that contract. If component1 is not designed to handle invalid data, you do not need to write a unit test for it, because it is not part of the contract. You would do the same for your validation components.

Now it would be up to your developers to make sure they architect the application in the way you described so that validation components get called before regular components. This is where you would perform some integration testing to make sure all of your components are hooked up correctly.

I was a little confused by the question, so I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi milleruva, thank you very much for your reply. You have answered my question perfectly (deapite having a hard time understanding it). I appreciate your help!